Deep linking through push notification's 'Accept' button doesn't work on Android 13 and above. It works fine on Android 12 and below in React Native
Deeplinking is not working through the push notification allow button above Android 12. When I hit the accept button in the notification, it does not navigate to the page.It works fine on Android 12 and below.
(React Native)
while checking on logcat got this :
"NotificationService     system_server    E  Indirect notification activity start (trampoline) from com.pickyassist.tb blocked"
I changed the firebase to the current version, but the same issues
files:
package.json
{
  "name": "Picky_Assist",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^11.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native/gradle-plugin": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.10.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.3",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-battery-optimization-check": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "Camera",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Microphone",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.8",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.85",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.85",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4",
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": {
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
    }
  }
}

android\build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = '1.9.22' 
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
}

android\app\build.gradle

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
import com.android.build.OutputFile


react {
  
}


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    namespace "com.pickyassist.tb"
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    
    defaultConfig {
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        applicationId "com.pickyassist.tb"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1127
        versionName "1.1.17"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release{
              if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
           
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
          
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.5.0'  // or the appropriate version
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
     // Firebase Cloud Messaging (Java)
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

   
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')

   
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


   

}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

